# Click button. Javascript alert box. If click OK, page reloads and need to create php variable with html input form value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

User clicks on Delete button. Javascript alert box popups with OK and Cancel. If user clicks OK, then page reloads (post form) and I need to create php variable with value from here `name="confirm_delete"`)

Here is my code

```
<form action="<?php echo (htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) ?>" method="post">

<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">

<input type="hidden" name="confirm_delete" id="confirm_delete" value="0" >

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#delete").click(function(){

    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (answer){
    return true;
    document.getElementById('confirm_delete').value = 1;
    } else {
    return false;
    document.getElementById('confirm_delete').value = 0;
    }

  });

});
</script>
```

Then `print_r($_POST['confirm_delete']);` but value always is 0. That means that `document.getElementById('confirm_delete').value = 1;` does not work.

Please, advice what need to correct

Comment: place your return statements after the `document.getElementById()` commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your javascript code by following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#delete").click(function(){

    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (answer){
    document.getElementById('confirm_delete').value = 1;
    return true;
    } else {
    document.getElementById('confirm_delete').value = 0;
    return false;
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

You are using the `return true and false` first after that you are assigning the value. so return terminates from the function before assign the value. so first assign the value and then use the return.