# Adding Javascript value to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I'm trying to add a JavaScript variable to a hidden input field. How would I do this?

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="submitFormOnClick btn btn-warning pull-right"
        style="margin-bottom:15px; margin-top:15px;" id="bet">Bet
</button>

<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="keno">
<input type="hidden" name="task" id="task" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pickednumbers" id="pickednumbers">
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inc = 0;
    var pickednumbers = [];
    function myFunction(elmnt, color, id)
    {
        if(pickednumbers.length >= 20)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (pickednumbers.indexOf(id) === -1)
        {
            pickednumbers.push(id);

            elmnt.style.background = color;
            inc = inc + 1;
            if(inc >= 20)
            {
                document.getElementById('onColor').setAttribute("style", "background-color:green");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**What I need:**
All I want is to have the variable `pickednumbers` be sent with the input type hidden.

Comment: Where and how is `myFunction()` is being called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Storing array of objects in hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076219/javascript-storing-array-of-objects-in-hidden-field)

Comment: <div id="containerkeno" class="noselect">
                        <div id="box_one" onclick="myFunction(this, 'orange', 1)" class="box">1</div>. I know the variable is filled.with correct data. When I alert it, it has the data which need to be sent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button. Javascript alert box. If click OK, page reloads and need to create php variable with html input form value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420685/click-button-javascript-alert-box-if-click-ok-page-reloads-and-need-to-create)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply do this :

```js
var inc = 0;
var pickednumbers = [2,3,4,8];

document.getElementById("pickednumbers").setAttribute("value",JSON.stringify(pickednumbers));
```

```html
<button type="button" class="submitFormOnClick btn btn-warning pull-right" style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:15px;" id="bet">Bet
</button>

<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="keno">
<input type="hidden" name="task" id="task" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pickednumbers" id="pickednumbers">
```